# parsing source of a page to retrive table data and then export into xls

Tags: php, excel, parsing, dom

I have a need to dump the source of a page into a form, and have it spit out an xls file containing the contents of the page's tables.

the page I wish to parse has several tables on it, of varying rows and 11 columns. Each table has a header, which I don't need. I have researched using DOM, but I couldn't figure out a way to use that object for my application. I thought about using preg_replace() as well, but again, since I am dealing with source code, I think that that wont work.

Once I get the parse portion correct, I know how to write it to a xls file in php. I just cannot figure out how to go about this in php. Thanks in advance.

If it helps, this is what the table structure looks like for each table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
       </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe it helps: Save the HTML file to disk and import it in Excell. It should ask you which tables you want to import.

Comment: thanks, that would work fine, except I have 65 pages to go through, with about 10 tables on each page :(

Comment: DomDocument + XPath. But that's sort of clever shitting because I'm currently not in the position to provide an elaborated answer to your question.

Comment: Read manuals about DOM, SimpleXML, XPath. And excuse me, but your "designs" is a shame for any designer. Take some time to read books about web-design.

Comment: I came here to ask for advice, all of my knowledge is self taught, from actually coding. If you are so "worldly" with designs why do you use blogspot? Thanks for the constructive comments ass.

Comment: @Ryan, I use blogspot because I don't want to spend time to code my own blog-service, when working free solution exists. Also I want to have some place, which hosted not with my main sites ("do not keep all eggs in one basket"). Read books about coding and about design - it's very, very important. You will safe years of your time, if you will read books instead of trying to get all knowledges just from practice. And you can't react to advices adequately - think about it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started at least

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);

// Get all tables bodies
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            $textContent = $cell->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```